# I want to plot images using gridspec. How can I do that?

Tags: python

```
x=[1,2,3,4,5]
y=[2,4,5,1,2]

def plotting(x,y):
    Figure = plt.figure()
    plt.plot(x, y)
    plt.show()
    return Figure

Fig1 = plotting(x,y)
```

If this is not possible then how can we make a grid of 2 col and 4 rows and place separate images on it python?

Actual function is to long to paste it here after that it gives as a plot. So I have 8 plots and I want to place it side by side like 2 by 4 grid.

I am doing like this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just look at this link for the subplots in the same plots. it may help you to do that.
https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/scatter_star_poly.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-bars-and-markers-scatter-star-poly-py

it is a different plot. but use the subplot syntax for your need.

ignore if this is not what you are looking at it.

Comment: if not share the code here, so that i can be done